# Blank desktop upon install in VirtualBox on Windows 8.1

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox

I've successfully installed Debian in my VirtualBox on Windows 8.1, but I wished to have 
 Ubuntu. My machine is HP Envy with Intel i7 and 8GB RAM, NVidia GeForce GT 750M.

First strange thing I encountered is that the VirtualBox does not offer 64-bit Linux OS type alternative (and I actually was not able to run 64-bit Debian either). I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 32-bit. All I saw is a blank desktop.

I've read quite a bit on the issue and tried things. For example I updated NVidia drivers and enabled the Unity plug-in by the ccsm. But after I enter my login I still see a blank desktop and cannot even envoke a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T.

dmesg reveals the following:

nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.

nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

NVRM: No NVIDIA Graphics adapter found!

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a VM or as the host? If in a VM, why are you installing nvidia drivers in the VM?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu in a VM. I was (and am) wondering at which level virtualization is implemented. In my view it must be on the HW/FW level. Otherwise why is it configured in BIOS? A VM should not be using Windows drivers for virtualization. This (probably naive) thinking prompted me to even care of the NVidia drivers on Ubuntu. This however did not help:(

Comment: There are [virtualization capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) (which make VMs a lot faster) in modern CPUs. That's why it's configured in the BIOS (whether you enable these capabilities or not - if you don't you get the slower, pure software virtualization). However, this does not extend to the graphics card. I think if you disabled VT-X in BIOS, VirtualBox doesn't allow 64-bit guest. Have you disabled it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I enabled Virtualization Technology in BIOS and was later able to install 64 bit Ubuntu. 64-bit Ubuntu has a full functioning desktop from the beginning. The 32-bit version still has blank display, but this is not a prio issue for me any more.

Comment: @etxmsol If you consider this problem solved, I recommend [posting your solution as an answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the hint muru! I enabled Virtualization Technology in BIOS and was later able to install 64 bit Ubuntu. Obviously this option, disabled by default, made VirtualBox stick with 32-bit versions only. The 64-bit Ubuntu has a full functioning desktop from the beginning. The 32-bit version still has blank display, but this is not of much importance to me any more.